# Is Fable III going to be available on the PC?

Tags: fable-3, fable-series

So everything I have read says Fable III is only on XBox 360, which sucks because I do not have an XBox 360, however I am over at Gamefaqs.com and checking to see what they have on Fable: The Lost Chapters, since I was in need of an rpg to play and they have an entry for Fable III under the PC section. So has anyone heard anything about Fable III being ported to the PC?

Comment: Fable 3 will be on the PC via Games For Windows Live - [source](http://majornelson.com/archive/2010/05/21/fable-iii-sku-s-announced.aspx), unfortunately this question is too localized for our site.  If you have questions like this in the future please feel free to stop by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35) first.

Comment: I think Fable 2 was not available for PC, weird the third one will be

Comment: Yeah, two wasn't, three will be. I hope two will be made available, but maybe not. I don't see how this is too local though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer yes, Fable 3 is available on the PC, as [announced here](http://lionhead.com/fable-iii-on-pc-out-now/)

Comment: I guess no one remembers that Alan Wake was announced as being PC right up till the release date. At that point they said the PC version was 'delayed'. Only later was it cancelled. Who made Alan Wake? Microsoft Game Studios. Who made Fable III? You guessed it.

Comment: FYI It's on sale on Steam at the moment: http://store.steampowered.com/app/105400/